# Two dimensional oscillation movement: For what conditions does the solution of these Differential Equations give such trajectories?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, dynamical-systems

If the movement equation is like this

*two dimensional movement equations:*
[image]

where $x,z,t$ are variables; the other expressions are constant parameters.

For what conditions is the solution of this ODEs can get such trajectories, showed in the second half of the plot? The mass point will move in a certain confined region and cyclic mode.

*two dimensional ocillation movement*
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Math.SE].  What do you mean by "such trajectories"?  What properties of the plot you've provided are you most interested in?

Comment: Also, a nitpick:  that's not a PDE, that's a set of coupled ODEs.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert. Thanks for pointing out that erro. As for such trajectories, I mean the point mass moves in a cyclic mode, in a certain confined region, showed in the second half of the plot.

Comment: You should consolidate any constants into aggregate parameters for our purposes, since we do not really care about your physical application. You should also write your equations using MathJax.

Comment: From the looks of it, you seem to have $x''=-ae^{-kz} \sin(kx-\omega t)+bx',z''=ae^{-kz} \cos(kx-\omega t)+bz'+c$ where $a,b,c,k,\omega$ are constants. In terms of the dynamical analysis, I would try to look for some kind of "energy". For example there is ostensibly a friction since $b<0$ (assuming $\eta,r>0$), so that produces some "energy decay". Unfortunately the other term is not the gradient of something since it is time-dependent so you are not just immediately done.

Comment: @lan, sorry for that cumbersome formula expressions. Im a new user and do not konw how to use MathJax in this website right now. I will see how to modify it lator. Thanks, you made clearer expresions. Energy is a good point! Which term do you mean can be the gradient of something?

Comment: The exponential/sine part. But it can't work, sadly.